# rails test database not clearing after some runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using rspec to test and I notice that after running the tests, it sometimes leaves some records in the test database. I'm not sure why. I have use_transactional_fixtures set to true in my config file. But they don't go away until I manually delete the records. Does anyone have a way to stop this?

EDIT; before i said it was only when tests fail. that's no longer true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem. [Before(:all) blocks are not transactional](http://mwilden.blogspot.com/2010/11/beware-of-rspecs-before-all.html)

Comment: Better source from [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/transactions): *Data created in `before(:all)` are not rolled back*.

Comment: Lol both links are now defunct. Here's the latest documentation as of today: https://rspec.info/features/6-1/rspec-rails/Transactions/

Answer (score -1):

Try [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem.

Truncation or Transaction strategy will work for you.

Caution: It **can** make your test suite run terribly slow.
Normally, proper use `before`, `after` in RSpec(if you are using it) works usually fine.

Comment: What do you mean proper use of before and after? What would be improper use? it's not a problem i see every time. I just don't know what would cause it to leave records around, so I'd like to stop doing that rather than adding a new gem.

Comment: This is the thing with the test suite - no matter what we think, data does persist in database, when it shouldn't. I've practically spent days trying to make the factories work. Last time, I was forced to use this gem, because of this. Though it did the job, perfectly. :)

Comment: I think if you avoid creating things outside of it blocks and before/after/around(:all) (and anything else that doesn't run per example, you should be good